# waitForElementPresent command fails in (Jenkins SeleniumHQ) but succeeds in SeleniumIDE

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am fighting an issue where my Selenium IDE Test succeeds when searching for specific elements on a page (Command=waitForElementPresent and Target=link=Related Sites) but that same command is failing when I run it from within Jenkins 'SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run'.

As an example; 
   waitForElementPresent    link=Related Sites  Timed out after 30000ms

I don't want to give the impression that all 'waitForElementtPresent' commands are failing because some are succeeding.

I just don't know if I'm dealing with a timing issue or I have to code the test differently when it will run within Jenkins 'SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run'.

Any advice to help me understand why I get different behavior for the same command is perplexing me and am unsure how to solve.

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your script has a default timeout set, that's why you are facing the problem.

Just try using `selenium.setTimeout("0")` in the constructor where you start selenium.